# Насколько высока будет нагрузка на сервер?

Tags: node.js

Есть миллиарды (или триллионы) картинок в базе данных и будет цикл на node js сравнивать перцептивный хеш картинок с каждой картинок в базе данных. насколько высока будет нагрузка на сервер и долгая ли будет загрузка?

Comment: Нодажс лопнет, как вероятно и сервер :) индексация будет идти неделями :) возможно и дольше, для таких задач используют кластеры, и конечно же не нодужс как софт индексации, это как минимум.

Comment: Если бы у вас реально было столько данных, то вы бы не задавали таких вопросов. Лучше расскажите свою реальную задачу и задайте реальный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Вы упретесь в совершенно другие проблемы. Во первых, хранение картинки "не бесплатно" и обычно в большинстве случаев на диске картинка занимает как минимум килобайта 4. Допустим картинок 1 миллиард. Простым перемножением получаем около 4 террабайт. А это достаточно многовато даже для современных серверов (но диски такие уже можно купить).

Но зайдем с другой стороны. Допустим, код идеально вылизан. В этом случае упремся в скорость чтения диска. Обычные hdd читают до 120 МБ/с (то есть, 15 мегабайт в секунду). Делим 4 террабайта на 15 Мб/с и получаем 266666 с = то есть, около 3 дней...

А если картинок триллионы, то нужно умножить на 1000. Дисков таких нет и десять лет ждать... а нужно ли это? Да и где сколько картинок найдете?

Поэтому, нужно просто вспомнить школьную математику и все станет на свои места.

Comment: Правда, если пойти по пути распределения данных дальше, то решение задачи (оставаясь достаточно фантастическим) может выглядеть и более оптимистично. Для миллиона клиентов, каждый из которых хранит часть всей базы (даже при ее десятикратной мультипликации) понадобится всего-то 40 мегов памяти на каждого. Дело за малым -) -- хорошей функцией хэширования, переводящей картинку (и ее поисковый образ) в разумное множество адресов потенциальных хранителей. В принципе, проектирование подобных систем (для смартфонов?) весьма интересная тема для обсуждения (но, боюсь, уже не для сегодняшнего ruSO)

Comment: Ну, сами-то перцептивные хеши не настолько тяжелые если их посчитать заранее...

Comment: Да все можно посчитать, но их  нужно посчитать. А тут мы упираемся в скорость чтения с диска. Но даже не смотря на это, надо как то эти картинки найти и записать. А запись обычно медленее...